# My visa was stolen

Tags: visas, lost-documents, italian-residents

My passport was stolen which includes my valid student visa to Italy. I have already arranged for travel and waiting for my flight on January 6 2019. I applied for a new passport and I have already obtain one. I still have a copy of that visa and receipt. Can I use this documents to travel?

Answer (score 4):

No. You need to apply for a replacement passport and visa.

Comment: Depending on the country, it may be possible to transfer the existing visa into a new passport without going through a full application process.  Check with the embassy.

Comment: @jpatokal I have never heard of that for a **stolen** passport. If damaged or passport expired or maybe even if lost, but never for stolen. Those are always voided.